# How to read a Q sphere representation?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, bloch-sphere, superposition

I'm trying to understand the Q-sphere representation of a 3-qubit system. I get that the 3-qubits are in a superposition of 2 different states. The first qubit (rightmost) is in a superposition of `0` and `1` with a phase difference of `pi`. And the other two qubits are in ground states. I hope I got this right till here.

What does the location of the point on the 1st ring represent? In the [documentation](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/docs/iqx/visualizations#q-sphere-view), it's mentioned that the latitude is the Hamming distance from zero state. What does that indicate?

[image: Q-sphere 2 qubits]

Answer (score 2):

We first need to understand what do we mean by Hamming Distance, simply put, for two strings of **equal length**, it is the number of different symbols in corresponding locations. For example: since we're exclusively dealing with binary strings, let's say we are calculating Hamming distance between `001` and `000`. Since only the right-most values differ, we get a hamming distance of $1$.

Another example: `101` and `010` has a hamming distance of $3$ since they are different at each position. Hamming distances are widely used in Coding Theory for [Error detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) and can also be used in Machine Learning as an [alternative](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/4-types-of-distance-metrics-in-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=Hamming%20Distance%20measures%20the%20similarity,the%20corresponding%20characters%20are%20different.&text=Since%20the%20length%20of%20these,can%20calculate%20the%20Hamming%20Distance.) measure to Euclidean distance. In both the applications it is used to objectively calculate how separate two values are, more the *hamming distance* more *dissimilar* they are considered to be.

Here, hamming distance has the same purpose, to calculate how dissimilar the states are. As you move farther away from $|000\rangle$ (going towards $|111\rangle$) the bigger will be the difference between the states and hence the bigger will be the Hamming distance. Going with the same logic, $|000\rangle$ and $|111\rangle$ have a hamming distance of 3 hence signifying that they are very different (or better said, completely opposite since `hamming distance` = `string length`).